# On Insert- Create new entry? Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I currently have two tables for which I have listed the codes below:

```
CREATE TABLE `class` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_title` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_of_students` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `enrolment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ssn` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I currently have the following statement, which when you enter something into 'Enrolment', and the class number you type in already matches a class_no in the table 'Class', then it adds whatever is typed into grade to no_of_students. What I now need it to do is if someone say typed into enrollment (2, 4, 6, 8) and the class_no 6 didn't already exist in the 'Class' table, it would add into 'Class' with the class_no as 6 and the no_of_students as 8.

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_add_one` 
AFTER INSERT ON `enrolment` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE class
    SET class.no_of_students = class.no_of_students + NEW.grade 
    WHERE class_no = NEW.class_no
$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I would suggest you write this logic into application layer instead of DB layer. Your logic should first check if the entry exist in the class table if not create an entry into Class first and then subsequently into enrollment.

Comment: Why should the number of students be 8 when only one student is enrolled in a class?

Comment: @Phil, I basically just need it that when you enter something into Enrolment, if the class number you type in doesn't exist, it will create it as a class_no in the Class table. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: @Shashank- I know this might sound strange, but I need it preferably in a Trigger :)

Answer (score 1):

(When you add an `enrolment` row do you really want to increment `class.no_of_students` by the value of `grade`? Seems like you might want to increment it by one. I wrote my answer assuming that.)

(I suspect you didn't show, in your question, the indexes definitions for your tables. I suspect you didn't show how your `id` columns get set. Presumably they are set with [autoincrement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html). If that's not true my answer is probably worthless.)

MySQL offers [an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You can change your trigger to use it, something like this (*not debugged*).

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert_add_one` 
AFTER INSERT ON `enrolment` 
FOR EACH ROW  
   INSERT INTO class 
             (class_no, no_of_students, grade)
     VALUES  (NEW.class_no, 1, NEW.grade)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY 
     UPDATE SET class.no_of_students = class.no_of_students + 1$
DELIMITER ;
```

For this to work correctly you need a unique index on `class.class_no`.  You can create it as follows:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX class_no ON class (class_no);
```

By the way, you need some sort of index on `class.class_no`. Without it neither your original trigger nor the new one will perform very well. And, your "business rules" seem to require each value of `class_no` to have just one row in the `class` table. So you may as well use a unique index.

**Pro tip**: Giving your columns accurate and descriptive names is almost always worth a lot of trouble early in your project. If, for example, the column `grade` actually is a count of new students, you'll create years of confusion. The more successful your project is, the more confusion you'll create.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this. The reasoning that i was incrementing ```class.no_of_students``` by the value of grade was just because i forgot to change the column name from Grade, to 'New Students'. I wanted whatever was typed into Grade, to ADD to the number of students in the 'Class' table. I hope that makes sense. I should've put that into the question- so my mistake. I now want it so that when i add something into the enrolment table, if the class_no doesn't already exist, it will add this new class to the class table. Hope that makes sense. Will give what you suggested a try :)

Comment: Hiya.. Tried this, also tried a couple of different approaches and attempted to debug, however i just get the same error of 'An unexpected error happened' and cannot figure out for the world of me why

Comment: The insert statement may be to blame... The class entity has no grade attribute

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in app logic or with a trigger, the later below:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_add_one AFTER INSERT ON enrolment FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
       DECLARE counter int DEFAULT -1;
       SELECT COUNT() INTO counter
       FROM class 
       WHERE class_no = NEW.class_no;
       IF counter = 0 THEN
          # no classes exist with enrolment ID
          INSERT INTO class (class_no) VALUES (NEW.class_no);

       ELSE:
          # class exists ++
          UPDATE class 
          SET class.no_of_students = class.no_of_students + NEW.grade 
          WHERE class_no = NEW.class_no;

       END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will give this a go :)